# How to access child div elements under a given condition with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

My main question is to calculate the last alert message, but any other information is also welcome.

I am trying to learn javascript (to use with greasemonkey later), but I am struggling a bit to grasp the DOM and how to process it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_test()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    // prints "found [object HTMLCollection] with length 8"
    alert("found " + elements + " with length " + elements.length);
    // prints "0:[object HTMLDivElement]"
    alert("0:" + elements[0]);
    // how to calculate the following?
    alert("for intereting one is AAAA and three is CCCC");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="interesing">
        <div class="one">AAAA</div>
        <div class="two">BBBB</div>
        <div class="three">CCCC</div>
</div>

<div class="boring">
        <div class="one">1111</div>
        <div class="two">2222</div>
        <div class="three">3333</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="my_test()" value="my test" 

</body>
</html>
```

So `elements` is now an array of elements and I can access each of them individually. But where can I find what methods/properties these elements have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to grab the elements and their children by class and not position, I would just write a short function that will return a collection of elements by class.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_test()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    // prints "found [object HTMLCollection] with length 8"
    alert("found " + elements + " with length " + elements.length);
    // prints "0:[object HTMLDivElement]"
    alert("0:" + elements[0]);
    // how to calculate the following?
    alert("for " + "interesing" + " " + "one" + " is " + C("one",C("interesing")[0])[0].innerHTML + " and " + "three" + " is " + C("three",C("interesing")[0])[0].innerHTML);
}

function C(cls,elm){
    if(!elm) elm = document;
    if(elm.getElementsByClassName) return elm.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    else{
        var t = [];
        var children = elm.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
            if(children[i].className.match(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + cls + "($|\\s)"))) t.push(children[i]);
        }
        return t;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="interesing">
    <div class="one">AAAA</div>
    <div class="two">BBBB</div>
    <div class="three">CCCC</div>
</div>

<div class="boring">
    <div class="one">1111</div>
    <div class="two">2222</div>
    <div class="three">3333</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="my_test()" value="my test" 

</body>
</html>
```

Please note that the `C` function I wrote to get elements by class is not a perfect solution, but it will work well enough in most cases and is easy to write on the fly. The alert works by getting the first element with a class of `interesing` (`C("interesing)[0]`) and then using that as a parameter in getting the first child element that has a class of `one` (`C("one",C("interesing")[0])[0]`).

If you are looking to grab those elements based on position or tag, then a different solution would be more appropriate. I am just assuming you are looking for those elements based on class, in which case a simple `getElementsByClassName` function would do all you need.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: It looks like I've solved your alert question but not quite answered the real question... I think. Remember that you can string together `getElementsByTagName`, so if you want the children `div` you can simply run a nested for loop, the first cycling through all the `div`, and if there are children, cycle through those.

Here is an example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    var str = "Parent DIV(" + elements[i].className + ") has ";
    var children = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
    if(children.length){
        str += "children: ";
        for(var j=0;j<children.length;j++){
            str += "{className:" + children[j].className + ",innerHTML:" + children[j].innerHTML + "},";
        }
    }else{
        str += "no children.";
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It fully answers this question, and 
by modifying it a bit, the first step is taken in achieving the end result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp